# Spring oAuth2 dual login: programatic and form

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I have this java j2ee app which is currently deployed into a tomcat container. Currently the app does it's own login and the goal is to split it and detach an Authentication Service (separate app).

I have created the Authentication service (a spring 4.x app) with the following security config:

```
        http.csrf().disable()
        .requestMatchers()
        .antMatchers( "/login_user","/oauth/authorize")
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin().loginPage("/login_user").permitAll();
```

My plan is this ... in the main app:
1. The user does something and the request is found to be non-authenticated
2. The main app redirects the call to the Authorization service , on "/oauth/authorize" 
3. The auth service redirects the call to the login page and validates the user and if all is successful , back to the "/oauth/authorize" endpoint ...
4. Now the authorization is performed and the call is redirected to the initiator ... all good ...

Now , my question is ... what happens if I am in the main app and want to request a token from the authorization service ? I want to do this programatically , from code ... not use the login page.

Is there any way you guys see I can mix the login form and normal programatic calls to get an token ? Have I mixed them improperly ?

Any ideas on how I should make login form and normal api calls to get token would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you
Mircea

Comment: How do you want to login without a login form? Do you want to login with user credentials or with client credentials?

Comment: Both. Because I cannot tell what will come in the future.The goal is to create an authentication service that does the following:  

1.  Permit login using a plain form login , that will be presented to UI applications when they access the main system - I am not sure wether the Login UI should be served by the authentication service though - but it makes sense that it does. 
2.  Permit login using user credentials, for api access
3.  Permit login using client credentials for api access